# Proportion of cell layers in the different areas of human cortex

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

I am looking for any scientific paper or book which could help me find the different proportion of layers across the different areas of the human cortex. I am working on a research project which includes investigating the areas with the highest proportion of layers 2 and 3 of pyramidal neurons. I have an idea of what some of these areas are, such as dorsolateral prefontal cortex, but I could not find any comparative material which describes the layer composition of the cortex area by area. Most of the papers I've come across either about an individual area and its cytoarchitecture, or about specific neuronal layers without comparing each area with respect to them.

Comment: You might check out the Allen Institute.